# Junit4 with Parameterized Test

Tags: java, junit4

I have the below Junit test, which I'm trying to run as a parameterized test to allow testing multiple condition with a test method, running this however

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;    
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
    public class ProductCategoryTest {


        private boolean isAggregate;
        private ProductCategory category;

        public ProductCategoryTest(boolean isAggregate, ProductCategory category) {
            this.isAggregate = isAggregate;
            this.category = category;
        }

        @Parameterized.Parameters
        public static List<Object[]> categoryList() {
            return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                    {true, new ProductCategory("A", "Laundry", ProductCategory.Type.Aggregate)},
                    {false, new ProductCategory("B", "Dryer", ProductCategory.Type.Individual)},
            });
        }

        @Test
        public void isAggregateProductCategory() throws Exception {
            assertEquals(isAggregate, category.isAggregateProductCategory());
        }

    }
```

The Exception I get:

```
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching categoryList with any parameter from org.junit.runner.Request$1@123772c4

    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:40)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:96)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: in the API    `@Parameters` annotation is used directly. Did you try that? (http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code on my PC it works all ok on my PC.
I suspect problems with libraries or JUnit runner that you have in your environment.

Try typing your own test runner. Here is an example how to do that:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

class ProductCategory {
    enum Type {
        Aggregate, Individual
    };

    public ProductCategory(String a, String b, Type t) {

    }
}

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
    public class ProductCategoryTest {


        private boolean isAggregate;
        private ProductCategory category;

        public ProductCategoryTest(boolean isAggregate, ProductCategory category) {
            this.isAggregate = isAggregate;
            this.category = category;
        }

        @Parameterized.Parameters
        public static List<Object[]> categoryList() {
            return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                    {true, new ProductCategory("A", "Laundry", ProductCategory.Type.Aggregate)},
                    {false, new ProductCategory("B", "Dryer", ProductCategory.Type.Individual)},
            });
        }

        @Test
        public void isAggregateProductCategory() throws Exception {
            //assertEquals(isAggregate, category.isAggregateProductCategory());
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(ProductCategoryTest.class);

            for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
               System.out.println(failure.toString());
            }

            System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
         }
    }
```

Comment: I'm having Spring boot starter test that configures Junit

Comment: Done that, the test runs without an issue then, so what now?

Comment: and just out of nowhere, the tests passes now!!! I'm not sure what is happening, all I have done is remove the main method I have posted based on your answer.

Comment: I would suggest cleaning up the project in Maven/Gradle and trying to check libraries you use for JUnit. When I look at stack trace - my concern would be that IntelliJ uses some JUnit imports that might be other to the imports you have in your test. (testRunners, etc.). Reviewing them and cross-checking could be a good idea.